# SAP Business Object in Open Text Content Server

Tags: sap, opentext

Can anyone tell me if importing into a Business Workspace that is a specific object type from the SAP Extended ECM Application and represents a SAP Business Object with Open Text Content Server is the same as importing into standard folders?

Can the same Object Importer from Live link be used or is it different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using object importer and importing into a business workspace is the same handling compared to a folder. Just quickly tested with oi 10.5.0.

What you cannot do is to import a business workspace itself. Therefore an OI extension would be required.

Comment: Thanks Claus. This actually just runs against something we read, so can you just confirm, you have an Open Text environment with XECM and after importing using the Object Importer you were able to see the documents from SAP? Cheers

Comment: I can confirm that I have xECM 10.5.1. I did not check whether the document is visible from SAP or not as SAP accesses the business workspace via soap webservices and the document does not need to store SAP-related information.  So no worries: once you have imported your documents into the business workspace they will be visible from SAP - if your user has the required permissions.